# Selling a library that uses linux system calls only

Tags: kernel

I know there is a lot of questions like this one but my question is a bit more specific than usual.

I'm writing a cross platform **shared**(.so) C library used for resolving mathematical sequences and I'd like to sell my library once I finish working on it. As you might know, **libc and glibc (as far as I know) are LGPL** which means that someone can link them to a proprietary/commercial software on Linux...

My problem is, that my library is compiled with **-nostdlib**, means that it doesn't use libc glibc routines neither it uses any other library on linux WHAT-SO-EVER, it's written from scratch and it's totally on it's own.

In the other hand, **my library includes Linux header files and makes extensive usage of linux system calls** such as memory mapping for custom memory management.

**The question:**
Can I make my library goes fully closed sources and sell it out knowing that the Linux kernel is under GPLv2 ? If so, does **(whether it's a static library or shared one)** has any effect on licensing ?

**P.S:** Technically speaking, it's a personal project and I just got the idea of selling it and make some money but if there is no way to do it that's also okay.

**Thank you for reading and for answering in advance.**

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about legal advice, not strictly programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot go Closed sources (at least not from the beginning) with GPLV2. Check here in the clause -

> You may copy and distribute the Program (or a work based on it, under Section 2) in object code or executable form under the terms of
> Sections 1 and 2 above provided that you also do one of the following:
>
> a) Accompany it with the complete corresponding machine-readable
> source code, which must be distributed under the terms of Sections 1
> and 2 above on a medium customarily used for software interchange; or,
>
> b) Accompany it with a written offer, valid for at least three years,
> to give any third party, for a charge no more than your cost of
> physically performing source distribution, a complete machine-readable
> copy of the corresponding source code, to be distributed under the
> terms of Sections 1 and 2 above on a medium customarily used for
> software interchange; or,
>
> c) Accompany it with the information you
> received as to the offer to distribute corresponding source code.
> (This alternative is allowed only for noncommercial distribution and
> only if you received the program in object code or executable form
> with such an offer, in accord with Subsection b above.)

In other inheriting a GPLv2 have to be open source at least for a certain period of time.

You can check the full specification here -

http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-2.0.html

**But again, you should consult a lawyer with the license for clear idea, we are not lawyers here, so you are most likely not to get a full or details answer here.**

Comment: I am glad it helped, please mark the answer. I usually go for BSD or MIT when using open sources, GPL has a lot of compatibility issues.

Answer (score 0):

You should check if the license of a **header** file propagates to your code or not (read also [this link](http://www.osnews.com/story/24553/Does_Android_Violate_the_GPL_Probably_Not).

Anyway, the problem can be avoided by relying on the **syscall** function (see **man syscall**) to avoid including the header files.

Answer (score 0):

Just like many other userspace binary libraries (eg, Nvidia, VMware) - there is both a kernel component and a userspace component.   For kernel it is always released as opensource, but never the userspace.   Kernel is just used for interfacing with hardware (like GPU and VMenter/VMexit) but userspace implements all the logic.    But if u think all interfacing with kernel is doable via syscall alone, then by all means do it - there is completely no need for source code release.

But selling libraries is really a poor choice of earning money - programmer nowadays have so many choices of mathematical libraries (from github, sourceforge and BSD etc).   For example,

https://github.com/bebraw/jswiki/wiki/Math-libraries   -> js based, meaning browser based is possible?
https://github.com/ampl/mp
http://www.netlib.org/cephes/ --> about 400 high quality mathematical functions in C.

And productivity need surpassing performance need - which may force them to use Python instead. (eg, SciPy).

http://scipy-lectures.github.io/advanced/sympy.html

But not to dissuade you too much, there is Intel Maths Kernel:

https://software.intel.com/en-us/intel-mkl

which is a commercial product.

Balance your option.